# How are they different `ChatBase.IsActive` false and true?

Tags: wtelegramclient

How are they different `ChatBase.IsActive` false and true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AliSalehi said, it's `false` if the user is not currently in the chat/channel (has `left`) or if the basic chat has been `deactivated` *(chat was migrated into a Channel supergroup)*.

It's also `false` if that `ChatBase` instance is one of the Forbidden or Empty types

For more information, see also:

- https://wiz0u.github.io/WTelegramClient/#terminology
- https://corefork.telegram.org/type/Chat types
- https://corefork.telegram.org/api/channel

Answer (score 2):

if you look at the implementation:

```cs
bool IsActive => (this.flags & (Chat.Flags.left | Chat.Flags.deactivated)) == (Chat.Flags) 0;
```

it check if the chat is `de-activated` or `user` has left the current chat or not.